# How to sort multi-array / nested map by value (e.g. from Firestore) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to get a multi-array / nested map sorted by value via JavaScript / TypeScript.

My array currently looks like this:

```
let array =
    [
      {
        classification: {
          company_id: 1
        },
        information: {
          name: 'C'
        }
      },
      {
        classification: {
          company_id: 1
        },
        information: {
          name: 'B'
        }
      },
      {
        classification: {
          company_id: 1
        },
        information: {
          name: 'A'
        }
      }
    ];
```

Now I'd like to sort by the `['information']['name']` values like this:

```
let array_sorted =
    [
      {
        classification: {
          company_id: 1
        },
        information: {
          name: 'A'
        }
      },
      {
        classification: {
          company_id: 1
        },
        information: {
          name: 'B'
        }
      },
      {
        classification: {
          company_id: 1
        },
        information: {
          name: 'C'
        }
      }
    ];
```

Does anybody know how to do that?
I'm especially struggling with the nested stuff...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `String.prototype.localeCompare`, you can compare the string values and based on that result, using `Array.prototype.sort` function, you can sort the arrays as follows.

```js
let array = [{
    classification: {
      company_id: 1
    },
    information: {
      name: 'C'
    }
  },
  {
    classification: {
      company_id: 1
    },
    information: {
      name: 'B'
    }
  },
  {
    classification: {
      company_id: 1
    },
    information: {
      name: 'A'
    }
  }
];

const result = array.sort((a, b) => a.information.name.localeCompare(b.information.name));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sort function. It would look like this:

```
const array_sorted = array.sort(
  (a, b) => {
    if (a > b.information.name) return -1;
    if (a < b.information.name) return 1;
    return 0;
  }, 0
)
```

You can invert the order by swapping the 1 and the -1. The sort function takes the first parameter of a function that returns -1, 1 or 0 which denotes the order and a second parameter that sets the initial value of  variable 'a' (optional). I have set the initial value to 0, that's just how I like to use the sort function as I think it makes it easier to write :)